# how can I load into memory a src file in crystal?

Tags: file, crystal-lang

The request is very straightforward: To load a file that is in my internal project `src/` directory into memory. Finally, print its content to the screen. Any help, please?

If we use `File.new("path/to/file")` it opens a file in the local file system, so that's not what I'm searching for.

Greetings.

Comment: Do you want the file contents be read at runtime or compiled into the binary?

Comment: @JohannesMüller , compiled into the binary. I'm making a CLI, one of its purpose is to display a template, so has to be inside the binary

Comment: for now, I'm just assigning all the content of the file to a class variable into another file using `module` scopes. There has to be a more elegant way of doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next Crystal release 0.27.1 will include a `read_file` macro. The change is already in master, but not released yet.

With this macro, you can just do `{{ read_file("path/to/file") }}` and it will expand to a string containing the contents of the file (at compile time).

Until 0.27.1 is released, a typical workaround is to shell out: `` {{ `cat path/to/file`.stringify }} ``

A more sophisticated solution for compiling many files into the binary and accessing them in a virtual file system at runtime is [schovi/baked_file_system](https://github.com/schovi/baked_file_system).

Comment: thanks, @Johannes Müller, that workaround work for me, let us just wait for the next release. greetings!